# Any way to stop Nginx from appending path to alias?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a VM running for development, in this VM I have nginx running on an internal IP (so no hostname) and as such all I can work with is locations rather than separate servers.

The server itself has `root /var/www/html;`, one of my locations, `/site1`, located in `/var/www/html/site1`, has a subdirectory named `public` that needs to be used whenever it is accessed. Basically anything going to `/site1/(.+)` needs to load `/site1/public/$1` instead (except for PHP files)

The issue I'm having is that no matter what setup I try, I cannot get it to not redirect to `/var/www/html/site1/public/site1/`, which it does as `/site1/` is the current location requested by the browser.

How do I solve this? Is there any way to rewrite without giving Nginx the chance to append the path?

I cannot set the server's `root` to `/var/www/html/site1/public`, which would fix this issue (that's the setup we have in the live environment), because then the other locations on this development VM stop working.

Relevant config;

```
root /var/www/html;

location /site1 {
    alias /public;
}

location ~* ^/site1/.*\.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/site1/application/entry.php;
}
```

Comment: When you say other locations stop working, that is probably because you have something wrong in your config so that may be the thing to concentrate on. Locations are a hierarchy so it could just be a case of getting them in the right order.

Comment: The other locations stop working if I change my `root` because they're just subdirs in `/var/www/html` that don't need any extra configuration besides the standard/default `/` location and PHP-FPM location block. I tried setting the roots in each block separately (which really shouldn't ever be necessary) but that just threw an error because I had a duplicate `root`

Comment: Your `alias` approach does not seem to be fine. Replace it with the full path to the directory and you should have what you want to achieve. So IMO it should look `alias /var/www/html/site1/public`

Comment: @Piotr doing that just makes it route to `/var/www/html/site1/public/site1/` rather than the expected `/var/www/html/site1/public`. Regardless of what I do, it always appends `site1/` to it